# symmetric and alternating tensors in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

The following is an excerpt from Chern's [Lectures on Differential Geometry](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3812):

[image]

### [image]

> I don't see how the proof shows the other direction of the set inclusion. Would anybody explain the logic in the "furthermore" part of the proof?

---

The following are definitions of the notations:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In essence, the content in the box wants to show that $P^r(V)\subset S_r(T^r(V))$ and $\Lambda^r(V)\subset A_r(T^r(V))$. This is first done by showing that $P^r(V)\subset S_r(P^r(V))$ and $\Lambda^r(V)\subset A_r(\Lambda^r(V))$, and this holds by the invariances mentioned between "Furthermore" and "Therefore". Then we notice that $S_r(P^r(V)) \subset S_r(T^r(V))$ and $A_r(\Lambda^r(V))\subset A_r(T^r(V))$, and this is since $P^r(V)\subset T^r(V) \supset \Lambda^r(V)$, as $T^r(V)$ contains all tensors of order $r$, thus all of $P^r(V)$ and $\Lambda^r(V)$. At least, that's what I get out of it.

Comment: Yes, you need to argue that $P^r(V)\subset S_r(T^r(V))$. If you take a symmetric tensor $x$, then $\tau(x)=x$ for any permutation $\tau$, so $x=S_r(x)\in S_r(T^r(V))$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially from A.Sh's and Ted Shifrin's comments.

"a symmetric tensor is invariant under the symmetrizing mapping" shows that $S_r$ is an *identity* map on $P^r(V)$ and thus $P^r(V)=S_r(P^r(V))\subset S_r(T^r(V))$.

Similarly, "an alternating tensor is invariant under the alternating mapping" shows that $\Lambda^r(V)=A_r(\Lambda^r(V))\subset A_r(T^r(V))$.

---

What confused me was the word "invariant". It is not only that $P^r(V)$ is invariant under $S_r$, which would give $P^r(V)\supset S_r(P^r(V))$, but also that every element in $P^r(V)$ is invariant under $S_r$, which means that $S_r$ is an *identity* map on $P^r(V)$ and thus $P^r(V)=S_r(P^r(V))$.

(Yes, this is a stupid question.)